# Using a data-attribute to set an option on jQueryUI calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to use a "data-dateformat" attribute to set the dateformat option of a jQueryUI Datepicker

so I can do this on my page

```
<input name="t1" type="text" class="datepicker" data-dateformat="MM YY"> 
<input name="t2" type="text" class="datepicker" data-dateformat="DD MM y">
```

and the datepicker will use the correct format

I tried

```
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
                  dateFormat: $(self).attr('data-dateformat') 
               });
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there some way to do that ?

Comment: What is self? Where do you assign it? Are you expecting it to be the input element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `self` value will not have the proper scope for individual elements. You need to loop over each datepicker.

Try this:

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.datepicker({
       dateFormat: $this.attr('data-dateformat')
    });
});
```

You can also use the jQuery `data` method.

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.datepicker({
       dateFormat: $this.data('dateformat')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this may work

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
              dateFormat: $(this).data('dateformat') 
});
```